# Read arbitrary amount of memory with process_vm_readv

Tags: linux, c, api, syscalls

For process_vm_readv the linux man page states:

> [...] (Avoid) spanning memory pages (typically 4KiB) in a single remote iovec element. (Instead, split the remote read into two remote_iov elements and have them merge back into a single write local_iov entry. The first read entry goes up to the page boundary, while the second starts on the next page boundary.)

I get why this is a thing but I don't quite understand how I should work around it. Do I somehow need to find out where the page boundaries are? Or does the function figure this out on it's own as long as I provide 2 remote_iov elements? And if I read more than 4kiB and potentially cross 2 page boundaries do I need to split the remote element into 3 parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read the whole paragraph -- that way of splitting the iovecs is not a hard requirement. It's only *supposed* to help in the case of a partial read, though it's not clear how it could help ;-)

That manpage is quite dubious and confusing; my testing shows that `process_vm_readv()` will always error out if the `iov_start` of the first iovec from the `remote_iov` list is not a valid address, but return a partial read if any of the pages spanned by `iov_start + iov_len` or the rest of the iovecs are not mapped in (which is expected and useful, but contradicts the emphasized parts below).

> Note, however, that these system calls do not check the memory  regions
>          in  the  remote process **until just before doing the read/write**.  Consequently, a **partial read/write** (see RETURN VALUE) may result if  one  of
>          the  `remote_iov`  elements  points  to  an  invalid memory region in the
>          remote process.  No further reads/writes will be attempted beyond  that
>          point.   Keep  this  in  mind  when  attempting to read data of unknown
>          length (such as C strings  that  are  null-terminated)  from  a  remote
>          process, by avoiding spanning memory pages (typically 4KiB) in a single
>          remote iovec  element.   (Instead,  split  the  remote  read  into  two
>          `remote_iov`  elements  and  have  them  merge  back  into a single write
>          `local_iov` entry.  The first read entry goes up to  the  page  boundary,
>          while the second starts on the next page boundary.)
>
> [...]
>
> This return
>          value may be less than the total number of requested bytes, if  a  partial  read/write occurred.  (Partial transfers **apply at the granularity
>          of iovec elements.  These system calls won't perform a partial transfer
>          that  splits  a  single  iovec  element**.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Got quite confused by the manage.